# Parameters stored in Ember router

Tags: ember.js

I would like to store custom parameters associated to any route; is it possible to store them in the router map? Something like:

```
this.route('aboutUs', {path: 'about-us', langIndex: '1'});
```

and then how can i recover the langIndex value from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router map is not designed to store transient data which you later need in your controller. For something like your use case to work you should rather do it like this:

```
App.AboutUsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  langIndex: '1'
  ...
});
```

And then inside the route corresponding controller you could get your variable like:

```
App.AboutUsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  someMethod: function() {
    // get here the variable stored in your route
    // this.get('target') always refers to the controller
    // corresponding route
    this.get('target').get('langIndex');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.